# Bypass water heater with Manablok system

Tags: water-heater

My water heater broke this morning ... will be replacing on Monday. I have a manablok system with all kinds of shut-off valves. How do I know which valve(s) to shut off to bypass the hot water heater? I have shut off all the hot water valves on the manablok ... it’s the other valves in the plumbing lines that I am referring to. I am not a plumber, but I do understand the basic workings.

Comment: The lines should be labelled.  If not, you'll need to either trace them to find the ones to/from the water heater or try them out until you find the right ones.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. There are often shutoffs right next to the water heater; adding photos of the manifold and water heater would be helpful. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Good morning. Thank you jwh20 and Daniel. I did find the valve and now have running cold water until I can get a new water heater tomorrow. Thanks again!